# JS D3 CSV Import Syntax Error: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, d3.js, token

I am trying to import a csv file into D3 and am unable to do so because of the following error:

```
Exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 3]
```

It doesn't specify a line where the error is.

I have pared the code down to basics and still does not work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            d3.csv("Capita for FM.csv", function(data) {
                debug(data);
            });   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note I'm using debug instead of console.log because I'm using the JSC build for Sublime.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Where is the error appearing?  In the browser's console or JSC's output?

Comment: It is in the JSC output

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and checked what `data` looks like?

Comment: I created the data in R - simple and small. It is 50 cities and a corresponding values so Washington, 50,000, Seattle, 25,000.....